# Unexpected scroll after click on link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some troubles with adding links to my html file. I am using this codepan and I am trying to add a link which should redirect me to another div. Unfortunately, after clicking on the link it took me to the div but with any scroll movement, it takes me back to the previous position. Does anyone have any idea why it is not working properly?

```js
var page = document.getElementById('page');
var last_pane = page.getElementsByClassName('pane');
last_pane = last_pane[last_pane.length-1];
var dummy_x = null;

window.onscroll = function () {
  // Horizontal Scroll.
  var y = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  page.scrollLeft = -y;
  
  // Looping Scroll.
  var diff = window.scrollY - dummy_x;
  if (diff > 0) {
    window.scrollTo(0, diff);
  }
  else if (window.scrollY == 0) {
    window.scrollTo(0, dummy_x);
  }
}
// Adjust the body height if the window resizes.
window.onresize = resize;
// Initial resize.
resize();

// Reset window-based vars
function resize() {
  var w = page.scrollWidth-window.innerWidth+window.innerHeight;
  document.body.style.height = w + 'px';
  
  dummy_x = last_pane.getBoundingClientRect().left+window.scrollY;
}
```

```css
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  color:#FFF;
  font-family:Helvetica;
  font-size:200%;
}
#page {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:#CCC;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
}
.pane {
  flex:0 0 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color: #45CCFF;
}

.pane:nth-child(4n+2)  {
  background-color: #49E83E;
}
.pane:nth-child(4n+3)  {
  background-color: #EDDE05;
}
.pane:nth-child(4n+4)  {
  background-color: #E84B30;
}
.pane:last-child {
  background-color: #45CCFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="pane"><div>Looping Horizontal Scroll</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>2</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>3</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>4</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>5</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>Last</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>Looping Horizontal Scroll</div></div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqzGJB

```
<div id="page">
  <div class="pane"><div>Looping Horizontal Scroll</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div><a href="#test">hello</a></div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>3</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>4</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div id="test">5</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>Last</div></div>
  <div class="pane"><div>Looping Horizontal Scroll</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ensure all code required to understand your question is posted as part of the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

So I finally have the solution for JS:

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(event => {

  var el = $(event.target);
  var href = el.attr("href");
  var destEl = $(href).closest(".pane");
  var yPosition = destEl.offset().left + window.pageYOffset;

  console.log(yPosition, {window})
  window.scrollTo({top: yPosition,left: yPosition,behavior: 'smooth'});
  event.preventDefault();

  $(".pane").each((i, e) => {

    console.log($(e).offset().left);
  });
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = jQuery(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');}
});
```